# Can my organism see?

Tags: science-based, biology, xenobiology, anatomy, genetic-engineering

The aliens on my book have two human like eyes but instead of a retina they have a layer of bacteria with the proteins that cones and rods produce! Could my aliens see?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

### This is a clever idea which could work

The photoreceptors of the retina are a layer of cells, and it is entirely possible for those to be replaced by cells of a different species if they do the same thing.  Chemical signals (neurotransmitters) are the only thing telling the next layer of cells whether you see something, and bacteria can make those also.

The idea has some challenges, none insurmountable:

- A bacterium is *usually* ([not always](https://www.cnn.com/2022/06/23/world/worlds-largest-bacteria-magnifica-intl-scli-scn/index.html)) much smaller than a human cell.  So a bacterial retina probably wouldn't look like ours.  You could simply add more cells, perhaps entwining synapses of the bipolar cells deep into a bacterial colony.  Alternatively, the bacteria could live inside "retinal" cells that are otherwise without pigment.  This would be like mitochondria (distant descendants of proteobacteria) which live inside human cells.
- The bacteria have to *get* to the retina somehow.  This implies the organism has some way to flag "good" bacteria and let them circulate through the blood or lymph throughout the body until they reach the right spot.  They may also need a way to cross into the body at the intestine, if they are eaten, or at some other surface.
- The organism needs to *find* the bacteria somehow.  For this there are two ideas I like:  (1) they might be transmitted from one animal to another on purpose (after being identified as "good" bacteria). (2) the animals might actually transmit bacteria as part of their genetics.  For any animal *on Earth* the gametes carry only one genome - but another planet may be different.  There you might have, from the moment of conception, a cargo of spores from other organisms, the equivalent of corn and potatoes and even your pet dog, which you can release into the environment later in life.
- You have to *be able to tell* which bacteria are good.  There's nothing more straightforward than for your seeing-eye bacterium to stop producing photoreceptors and other useful things and just be a parasite in your body.  So we have to suppose that the brain of these people, seeing the landscape, is constantly noticing which bacteria are "dead pixels" or otherwise unreliable.  It may target those to be destroyed by the immune system (revoking their individual immunity by withdrawing whatever tag the body was using to say they were friendly).  Also you may identify the very most accurate bacteria over time, using something similar to long term potentiation for memory to mark the synapses connecting to them, and give those extra nutrients and carry them off safely to be shed in tears or otherwise passed on to other members of your species.
- You want a *reason* for all this.  Yes, life might have evolved another way, but this is a complicated Rube Goldberg mechanism for something we do more simply.  So why?  My guess is, using external bacteria mean that you can pick up *different photoreceptors for different environments*.  When one set stops working well, you cut down on feeding them, and if you pick up some other bacteria that see better, your brain tells your body to support those instead.

I picture these being used on a planet with a lot of different light environments.  On Earth we have sunlight and moonlight and starlight, and our built-in cones and rods do fairly well for the first two at least.  Let's say your planet is ... a tidally-locked planet around a red dwarf, with an unbearably hot day side and unbearably cold night side.  Your life forms forage within a twilight zone on the surface, or venture further to either side in caverns formed by fluids of different temperatures and chemical compositions that flow near the boundary.  The caverns are lit by bright bioluminescent organisms of different colors and intensities.  (There's no good reason for that, but it looks cool and few authors can pass up the opportunity to make them less boring)  In this environment, evolving a single unchangeable retina for your eyes just didn't work out very well, so your system prevailed.

Comment: actually several organisms on earth transmit more than one genome at a time, mostly  seed plants or endosymbiotic bacteria. Also your bacteria could be self-policing, after all keeping the host alive is in their best interest as well.